# Decode some special characters fails with utf8_decode

Tags: php, decode

I'm trying to import data from Excel and when cells have some special characters the `utf8_decode` function fails. In concrete with:

Special slash: l’Olleria
Special double slashes: “word”

How can I decode this characters?

```
Original data -> “camión”  c’amión
$data = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow ( 0, $row )->getValue();
print -> â€œcamiónâ€  wâ€™ordb
$cleanedData = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $data);
print ->"cami?n"  c'ami?n
```

Comment: You first need to encode utf8 characters before you can decode them.

Comment: `utf8_decode($utf8_encode($data)) ` ?

Answer (score 0):

replace Microsoft Word/Excel version of single  and double quotations marks (" " ' ') with  regular quotes (' and ")

```
iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $some_string);
```

Comment: Ok, and then the accents? `utf8_decode(iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str))` doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this then:

```
$asciiEncoded = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $utf8String);
$utf8Decoded = utf8_decode($utf8String);
$newString = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($utf8Decoded); $i++) {
    $newString .= substr($utf8Decoded, $i, 1) == '?' ? substr($asciiEncoded, $i, 1) : substr($utf8Decoded, $i, 1);
}
```